# Ad Not Visible in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, ads

I have just installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and was trying out Ads SDK, I have currently set my target to Windows Phone 8.0. The problem is that whether I  use the Ad Control with the test ad or with the Ad ID from the pubcenter, I only get a blank space in my emulator. I have tried everything and followed the step by step procedure given on the Ad SDK Forum.

Here is my code and the screenshot.

[image: No Ad Visible]

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,15">
                <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" Height="80" Width="480"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Dimensions Weather And News" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="News Section" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontSize="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Add error_occured event and look error. I Think you forget one capability.

Comment: Could you please describe me more about what you are suggesting? Also, I have checked for capabilities many times.

Comment: Thank you, post the answer. I used error_occurred and found thatI was missing capabilities that are not defined in the guide or forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Error_occured Event in your control Ad for know error.
I think you forgot 1 or more capabilities.
Information => [Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities(v=msads.20).aspx)

Comment: I forgot USER_ID AND MEDIALIB capabilities.